# Commit merge conflict fixes to the branch with changes

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a `master` and a branch `A`.

I'm trying to get changes to go from `A` to `master`.

However, there are merge conflicts.

Currently, when I use `git merge` or similar things (for example, IntelliJ's built-in merge conflict resolver or SourceTree + KDiff3), when there are conflicts, I can fix them.

However, the fixes I make are done on the `master` branch.

This means with a protected remote `master` (i.e. via GitHub) where you can't push directly to `master`, I can't actually commit the merge conflict fixes.

Is there a way to make edits committed to `A` and then merge them altogether into `master`?

I can get this behavior using GitHub's merge conflict editor - when you use it, it commits the changes into branch `A` and then you still have to do code review, etc. to commit into `master`. But  I would like to be able to do the merge conflict resolution in my IDE, ideally.

Edit: further searching has suggested that I can actually merge `master` into `A`, resolving conflicts in the process, and then merge `A` back into `master`. Can anyone confirm if that sounds right?

Comment: If your fixes are made on master branch then your current HEAD is master. I guess you have to checkout to branch A first and then make the conflict changes.

Comment: your latest comment sounds right: 1)  ```git checkout A && git merge master``` (this merges `master` into `A`); 2) resolve conflicts; 3) `git add <what needs to be committed> && git commit`; 4) `git checkout master && git merge A`; Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, just tried that and it worked great! Feel free to post as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

If your fixes are made on master branch then your current HEAD is master. I guess you have to checkout to branch A first and then make the conflict changes and then do a merge to master.